# What is the difference between a polyp and a papilloma?

Tags: tumors

I hope the question was clear because I have got nothing to clarify it with. I was reading Robbins and its Neoplasia chapter when that confused me a bit. Can anybody clear this up for me?
According to Robbins:

> Papillomas are benign epithelial neoplasms growing on any surface, that produce microscopic or macroscopic fingerlike fronds.
>
> A polyp is a mass that projects above a mucosal surface... to form a macroscopically visible structure.

I understood these sentences quite good enough but what is the fundamental quality that sets them apart? I still am not confident regarding their differences (and cannot differentiate them, say, on a patho slide)
A little bit of histology here would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **polyp** is a broad term that is defined *only* by its **macroscopic** appearance. So, I'll just repeat the definition provided in the question:

> A polyp is a mass that projects above a mucosal surface... to form a
>   macroscopically visible structure.

Polyps can be categorized by their **microscopic (type of cell)** characteristics, for example:

> **Papillomas** are benign *epithelial* neoplasms growing on any surface,
>   that produce microscopic or macroscopic fingerlike fronds.

Examples of other subtypes of [polyps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyp_(medicine)) (based on microscopic differences) are adenomas, inflammatory and hyperplastic polyps, hamarthomas, etc.

So, papilloma is a type of polyp.